# Force Entourage to display times in 24-hr format

Tags: macos, formatting, entourage, timestamp

In Microsoft Outlook, displayed time matches system preference time (which I always set to 24-hr).

However, Entourage does not seem to follow the system preferences for time display.

Is there a way to make Entourage display send/receive timestamps in 24-hr format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft says that Entourage uses the System time settings (see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/help.mspx?MODE=ct&CTT=PageView&clr=99-2-0&target=1565f129-0a39-4b3d-8586-fbf823d76c321033&srcid=&ep=8&rtype=2&pos=1&quid=12008e31-a424-4cf4-b690-9494d53e5258)). If it's not working, it's a bug.

It does mention, though, that "After changing the date or time settings, **the new settings will not take affect in Entourage until you open an item** or click a different folder in the folder list."

Comment: I've had my system format on 24-hr since January (when I got it), and Entourage hasn't followed that yet :-\

Comment: let me take that back: I've had it *displaying* as 24hr. Grrr! Thanks for the pointer

Comment: why would the "displayed" and "actual" time formats be different?